# problems with mvc5 when I run my application

Tags: html, css, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

why I am giving this error when I try to run

error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8cRc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/unn6X.png)

code html:

```
@model TornarPagina
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ABC do ABC ‹ Central de Atendimento";
    ViewBag.Description = "Com problema ou dúvidas, acesse nossa centra de atendimento ABC do ABC, que responderemos todas as suas dúvidas";
    ViewBag.Keywords = "ABC, Notícias, Eventos, Guia Comercial, Região do ABC";
    ViewBag.Author = "Portal do ABC do ABC";
}

<div class="container padding">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="visible-xs">
                <figure class="ad-mobile">
                    <a href="#" title="Publicidade Mobile" alt="Publicidade Mobile"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/ad-mobile.jpg" alt="Publicidade"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="visible-sm">
                <figure class="ad-sm">
                    <a href="#" title="Publicidade"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/ad-topo.jpg" alt="Publicidade"></a>
                </figure>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <h1>Faça do <b>ABC</b>do<b>ABC</b> sua página inicial</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row center-block col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="ie padding2">
            <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ie" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <div class="titulo model1">
                    <img src="~/Images/TornarPagina/ie.png" />
                    <h2>Explorer</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse conteudo model1-1" id="ie">
                <span>1</span><p>Clique no menu Ferramentas, que fica ao lado direito da barra de endereços e está sinalizado com uma imagem de engrenagem. Escolha "Opções da Internet".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/ie-img-1.png" />
                <span>2</span><p>No item Home page, escreva http://www.abcdoabc.com.br e, por fim, clique em "Ok".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/ie-img-2.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row center-block col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="safari padding">
            <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#safari" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <div class="titulo model2">
                    <img src="~/Images/TornarPagina/safari.png" />
                    <h2>Safari</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse conteudo model1-2" id="safari">
                <span>1</span><p>No navegador da Apple precisa primeiro ir à página principal do ABCdoABC. Depois, basta entrar, pelo menu, na caixa "Preferências" e clicar sobre o botão "Usar a Página Atual</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/safari-img-1.png" />
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/safari-img-2.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row center-block col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="google padding">
            <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#google" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <div class="titulo model3">
                    <img src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome.png" />
                    <h2>Chrome</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse conteudo model1-3" id="google">
                <span>1</span><p>Vá ao menu Ferramentas (lado direito de endereço) e escolha a opção "Configurações"</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome-img-1.png" />
                <span>2</span><p>Em Inicialização, selecione a opção "abre uma página especíica ou um conjunto de páginas". Em seguida, clique em  "Configurar Páginas".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome-img-2.png" />
                <span>3</span><p>Em adicionar uma nova página, digite: "http://www.abcdoabc.com.br". Por fim, clique em "Ok".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome-img-3.png" />
                <span>4</span><p>Caso, por padrão, o Chrome não mostre o ícone de casa (Home page), que leva diretamente à página inicial, volte ao menu Ferramentas e clique na opção "configurações". Em Aparência, escolha a opção "Mostrar botão Página Inicial".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome-img-4.png" />
                <span>5</span><p>Clique em "Alterar" e selecione "Abrir esta página". Na caixa que abrir, digite: "http://www.abcdoabc.com.br". Por fim, clique em "Ok".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/chrome-img-5.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row center-block col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

        <div class="firefox padding">
            <a class="" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" href="#firefox" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
                <div class="titulo model4">
                    <img src="~/Images/TornarPagina/firefox.png" />
                    <h2>Firefox</h2>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse conteudo model1-4" id="firefox">
                <span>1</span><p>Para quem usa o Firefox, o meio mais fácil é clicar sobre o símbolo da "Terra" na caixa de endereço e arrastá-lo até o ícone da casa. Depois, basta dar "Ok".</p>
                <img class="img-responsive" src="~/Images/TornarPagina/firefox-img-1.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

====================================================================

can anyone help me , do not know why is giving this error, the return I assembled a view and html page that calls this controller

thank you

Comment: What exception is being thrown?

Comment: Include the details in your question, not images of it.

Answer (score 0):

**Make Sure You Are Using MVC**

Firstly, makes sure that you actually have MVC (i.e. `System.Web.Mvc`) included within your Project (via a NuGet package or manually pulled in).

**Check Your Namespaces**

Ensure that you have the proper namespaces references within your `web.config` file that handle MVC and its routing:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
        <namespaces>
            <!-- Ensure that these are present -->
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="YourProject.Namespace" />
        </namespaces>
    </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

**Clean and Copy Properly**

If things still aren't working, consider the following :

- Clean your existing solution.
- Ensure that the `CopyLocal` property is set to `True`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the complete error?

Also, how are you routing the urls? I would start looking under App_Start/**RouteConfig.cs**. For example if the default route looks something like this {controller}/{action}/{id} the url you are attempting to reach is Home/TornarPagina.

Another trick is to go to your controller in Visual Studio, right click > Go To View(Ctrl+M, Ctrl+G) and that will take you to the view for that controller.

Here is tutorial [a link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/adding-a-view) on how to create views with controllers.